# Avro schema cannot deserialize autoregistered avro schema by connector

Tags: avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-schema-registry

We are trying to consume a topic that has data emitted by a connector. We are using a handwritten schema that matches the data in the topic.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Event",
  "namespace": "com.example.avro",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "type",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "entity_id",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "emitted_at",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": ["null", "string"],
      "default": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Unfortunately it cannot deserialize this because of the auto-registered schema by the connector.

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Value",
  "namespace": "postgres.public.events",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "id",
      "type": "string"
    },
    {
      "name": "type",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "entity_id",
      "type": [
        "null",
        "string"
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "emitted_at",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "io.debezium.time.ZonedTimestamp"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    },
    {
      "name": "data",
      "type": [
        "null",
        {
          "type": "string",
          "connect.version": 1,
          "connect.name": "io.debezium.data.Json"
        }
      ],
      "default": null
    }
  ],
  "connect.name": "postgres.public.events.Value"
}
```

We are getting the following error:

> Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not find class postgres.public.events.Value specified in writer's schema whilst finding reader's schema for a SpecificRecord.

How do we resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can either download the schema from the registry instead of defining your own (there's maven plugins to do this), or change the namespace+name of your own schema such that the generated class will match.

Adding an alias might work as well, but I've not had much experience/luck with that, personally.